# A condition for a sequence defined by a recurrence relationship to all be integers.

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in a specific sequence $\{a_n \}$ defined by a simple recurrence relationship: $$a_n = \frac {a_{n-1} ^2 +c} {b} $$ where $b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to find all $b,c$ such that there exists some integer $a_1$ such that $\{a_n\} $ are all integers.

I think that this would be a well-known problem, but I have trouble finding it. Even if this is not well-known, I cannot find a way to solve this question.

For example, if $b=3$ and $c=1$, it is fairly trivial that there exists no such $a_1 $. if $b=3$ and $c=2$, we can let $a_1 = 1 $ to make all $\{a_n \}$ be integers. However, I cannot easily work this out even in a single case, such as $b=3, c=17$. Furthermore, how can I find all $(b,c)$ such that there exists some $a_1$ such that $a_n \in \mathbb Z$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: In the case $b=1 \$ this is the Mandelbrot recurrence. (It can be highly unpredictable)

Comment: Considering your entire question revolves around how individual iterates behave, I thought you should know that there is no closed form solution.

Comment: @Zach466920 Actually the biggest problem is that I cannot easily figure out a way to work out even a single case.

Comment: Two trivial observations:1)  $-c$ has to be a quadratic residue modulo $b$. 2) If $c=m\,n$ and $b=m+n$, then $m$ and $n$ are fixed points. As an aside, for $b=3$, $c=17$, the longest run of integers I found is $29$, corresponding to $a_1=3080$.

Comment: Looks like $b=2,c=1$ and $a_1$ any odd number should be the only non-trivial solution.